# Rails/Paperclip "spoofing error" on PDF file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip in a Ruby-on-Rails app to manage various files, including uploaded PDFs.  I've had no problems with it in the past, including a PDF upload just a week ago; but then a couple days ago I went to upload a new PDF and it's failing: when I try to upload the file the edit form redisplays with a red dashed line around the upload button.

The logfile has this to say:

```
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename hwk2.pdf (video/x-flv from Headers, [#<MIME::Type:0x0000000180e548 @content_type="application/pdf", @raw_media_type="application", @raw_sub_type="pdf", @simplified="application/pdf", @media_type="application", @sub_type="pdf", @extensions=["pdf"], @encoding="base64", @system=nil, @registered=true, @url=["IANA", "RFC3778"], @obsolete=nil, @docs=nil>] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/pdf. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

It is in fact a PDF file (which I generated myself using pdflatex), and nearly all the info here agrees on that fact, except that "Headers" seems to think it's a Flash video (`video/x-flv`) for some reason.  What headers is this referring to and how can I fix them?  I have found the workaround that simply turns off the spoofing check (by making `spoofed?` always return false), but I'd prefer to actually correct the error if I can.

Versions of things in case they're relevant: `ruby 2.2.3p173`, `rails (4.0.0)`, `passenger-4.0.59`, `Apache/2.4.16`, `paperclip (4.2.4)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out, and it wasn't (I should have realised this) a RoR problem.  For reasons not entirely clear to me, my Firefox installation was identifying `video/x-flv` as associated with the `.pdf` extension (in addition to the real mime type).  Interestingly, I couldn't edit it within the application's preferences pane; but I could remove it from the `mimeTypes.rdf` file in my `.mozilla/firefox/blahblah.default` profile directory, and that fixed the problem.